# Download file from dropbox using C# WebClient - encoding issue

Tags: c#, sitecore, dropbox, sitecore8.2

I'm trying to download the file from Dropbox then create an attachment and send it in an email in WFFM form in Sitecore 8.2 update 5.  On my website, I use two types of file upload controls: regular asp.net MVC file upload and the upload from Dropbox. I created a custom WFFM control for this purpose and custom save action.
Both controls are using the same code for email submission and the regular file upload files are going through perfectly, unfortunately, when I try to upload a file from Dropbox and open the attachment in the email I get an error message:

"Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open "filename.pdf" because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

In the code I can see that the bytes[] file size which I get from regular upload is different from Dropbox. I guess something is not right with encoding/decoding but I'm running out of ideas.

Code for dropbox upload:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                        client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(this.DownloadProgressChanged);
                        file = client.DownloadData(this.FileLocation);
                        fileName = Path.GetFileName(this.FileLocation).Replace(Constants.FileUpload.DropboxQueryString, string.Empty);
                        var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(this.FileLocation).Replace(Constants.FileUpload.DropboxQueryString, string.Empty);
                        mimeType = MimeTypeMap.GetMimeType(fileExtension);
                    }
```

Then I use Convert.ToBase64String(file) to pass this value as a string (never mind why I need that but needs to be done in this way) in the form to custom save action Send Email Message and I decode it back while attaching the file:

```
private static IList<Attachment> RetrieveAttachments(string fileName, string mimeType, string file)
        {
            IList<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileFieldValue))
            {
                byte[] fileContent = Convert.FromBase64String(file);

                var actualAttachment = new MemoryStream(fileContent)
                {
                    Position = 0
                };

                var attachment = new Attachment(actualAttachment, fileName, mimeType);
                attachment.ContentDisposition.Size = actualAttachment.Length;
                attachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
                attachments.Add(attachment);
            }
            return attachments;
        }
```

Do you know how I should encode/decode the files uploaded from Dropbox or is there anything obviously wrong with the code above?